# Feynman type write up for particle physics observables?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, resource-recommendations, large-hadron-collider, heavy-ion

In gist: Struggling particle physicist (on the verge of giving up) 
needs qualitative writeup/article of the various aspects of heavy-ion physics:

1. Kinematics,transformation (Lab <-> Center of Mass), mid-rapidity for asymmetric, fixed target
2. The chiral magnetic effect, (I only know basic particle physics, zero theory).
3. Expectation, correlation formulae (Correlation of particles in heavy-ion collisions).
4. Fluctuation and critical point (via moments), (I did not study statistics)

---

I am a post-doctorate student in particle physics (experiment). From the beginning of my Ph.D, my knowledge about particle physics, kinematic, correlation, cumulant etc were weak. So, I could not grasp many popular results in our field. I can see the for collider experiment with symmetric nuclei (Au+Au) the midrapidity is y=0. But how do I calculate midrapidity at fixed target experiment? What will be mid rapidity in collider experiment but with asymmetric nuclei (deuteron - Gold).

I am also trying to understand Chiral Magnetic Effects in heavy ion collisions. But most of the papers, for example, https://arxiv.org/abs/0909.1717, you only get results and its interpretation. So, is there any paper/article/lecture series which instead of detailed mathematical equations, qualitatively describes the Chirality, C-violation, CP violation (and all sort of thigs happening in Heavy-ion collision).

For example, I don't even remember now what is chirality, how chirality is spontaneously broken and then restored in Quark Gluon plasma. 
Recently there are studies of Lambda particle polarisation measurements going on. It is written that lambda is polarised because the system produced in two-ion collided has huge angular momentum. To be honest, I only remember the classical momentum, angular-momentum etc. from graduation but have no idea how the Lamda polarisation happens in the heavy-ion experiment, and how the graph that is shown in papers, shows it is polarised.

The most problem I face is with fluctuation studies. What are the moments and whats normal distribution, skellam distribution, for example, https://arxiv.org/abs/1309.5681 this paper I try to understand but I have no idea for moments.

So I need to learn about distributions and moments. 
So basically I am looking for books/articles/write up which is suitable for readers who do not have prior experience in the field.

Comment: "I am a post-doctorate student ..." What's one of those?